# I am getting error with flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wilct.png)

I am getting error with flutter doctor --android-licenses
and I cant sloveed and when I run flutter docter it show
`Android license status unknown. Run`flutter doctor --android-licenses `to accept the SDK licenses. See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.`
I'm tired of this problem
I want to run flutter doctor --android-licenses with any erorr

Comment: sounds like you need to lower your Java version?

Comment: Try referring to this flutter issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124776 .Hope it helps.

Comment: ‪jdk-8u371-windows-x64.exe‬